# Update record in DynamoDB for reserved Keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Following data mapped in DynamoDB for record_id 7, I want to update customer with new value

```
"customer": {
            "value": "id2",
            "label": "Customer2"
        }
```

However, dyanamoDB does not allow to update because of  "ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: value".

Record in DynamoDB:

```
{
    "terms": "Terms",
    "action": {
        "value": "id1",
        "label": "In Progress"
    },
    "line_items": [{
        "product": "dd",
        "quantity": "10",
    }],
    "_id": "7",
    "customer": {
        "value": "id1",
        "label": "Customer1"
    }
}


   updateExpression = "set "
   updateValues = dict()
   expression_attributes_names = {}

   for key, value in dictData.items():  
     key1 =  key.replace('.', '.#')
     updateExpression +=" #{key1} = :{key},"
     updateValues[f":{key}"] = value
     expression_attributes_names[f"#{key1}"] = key

   table.update_item(
   Key={
    'id': item_id
   },
   UpdateExpression=updateExpression,
   ExpressionAttributeValues=updateValues
   ExpressionAttributeNames=expression_attributes_names
   )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid UpdateExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74920856/invalid-updateexpression-attribute-name-is-a-reserved-keyword-reserved-keyword)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UpdateExpression` expects a string and you are passing a list:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html#DDB-UpdateItem-request-UpdateExpression

I would also suggest you just print the values and check that they match the correct syntax expected for the parameters you're passing.

For nested values you just follow the same concept:

`#customer.#value`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.html#Expressions.ExpressionAttributeNames.NestedAttributes

Comment: Main issue that `customer.value` and `action.value` type of keyword used in given record. I am not sure how to replace with #.

Comment: Updated my answer to help you more.

Comment: I tried to update  key1 =  key.replace('.', '.#')
     updateExpression +=" #{key1} = :{key},"
     updateValues[f":{key}"] = value
     expression_attributes_names[f"#{key1}"] = key  but getting error ExpressionAttributeNames contains invalid key

Comment: Print the value of updateExpression and share it here

Answer (score 0):

it will be easier for me if you share the query expression you tried but in case of reserved words you need to rename the field in the query:

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        '_id': 7
    },
    UpdateExpression="set #val = :v",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":v": "false",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
      "#val": "value"
    }
)
```